# Couchbase on Google Container Engine resets itself

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase, google-kubernetes-engine, couchbase-java-api

I have deployed a 4 node Couchbase cluster using Docker images on the Google Container Engine with Kubernetes. I was able to access the Couchbase Console, look at the buckets, query etc. Now, after a couple of days, I go the Console URL and the Couchbase initial setup screen comes up! As though this is a fresh install. I can see that the nodes and pods are all still up and running. 
Had a similar problem on my Windows box with Docker cluster (No Kubernetes). I redeployed that again.
Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The containers never restarted?

Comment: No, they did not restart. I destroyed those instances and recreated them again.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy and recreate container instances all the underlying state is lost.

If you want to preserve the state of your couchbase installation you'll need to use a docker data volume. Just create one and mount your couchbase data file directory.

On gcp, you'll additionally  want to map a directory on the data volume to a persistent disk.